# How to scale down the desktop in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: gnome, 20.04, display, scaling

I have a big display that I connect to my notebook, but menus, taskbars, icons, and text look too big. I know I can individually change icons and text sizes but I wanted to scale down the whole display, similar to what the scale option does (in Display Settings) but down to 50% or 75% (not up to 200%). There is a [similar unanswered question for Kubuntu/KDE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1239060/scale-down-display-in-kubuntu-kde), but, as I am using the default Ubuntu distribution (Gnome), I thought that someone may have an answer in my case.

Comment: Have you considered the [fractional scaling](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2020/04/ubuntu-20-04-fractional-scaling-support-setting) feature of 20.04?

Comment: In fractional scaling, the scaling factor has to be bigger than 100%, such as 110% or 125%. I need to scale it to 50% or 75%.